# Questions regarding Unity3D's inheritance behavior

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, unity-game-engine

I'm building an Inventory system for my game, and I feel that I'm very unsure in regards to how Unity3D's inheritance system work. I know that there are plenty of Inventory systems out there, but I want to do this myself to learn.

Basically, I want to have an Inventory base class which "PlayerInventory", "ChestInventory", "DrawerInventory" etc. etc. can derive from. And this seems to work just fine:

Inventory.cs:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour {

    public int numberOfSlots = 0;

    public List<Slot> slots = new List<Slot>();

    public virtual void Awake () {
        Debug.Log ( "Inventory.Awake() - numberOfSlots = " + numberOfSlots );
        for ( int i = 0; i < numberOfSlots; i++ ) {
            slots.Add( new Slot() );
        }
        Debug.Log ( "Successfully created " + slots.Count + " slots!" );
    }

}
```

PlayerInventory.cs:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerInventory : Inventory {

    public new void Awake () {
        this.numberOfSlots = 30;
        base.Awake ();
        Debug.Log ( "PlayerInventory.Awake" );
    }

}
```

While this seems to work just fine, I find it a little messy. Questions:

- Can I (or should I) define numberOfSlots outside of Awake() in the derived class?
- Can I (or should I) avoid calling base.Awake() in the derived Awake() method?
- Anything else I've obviously done wrong? :)

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any awful flaws, but I would suggest you override Awake() in the derived classes since the base method is already virtual. Making a new Awake() suggests you want to make a completely new method, not caring about the base method. Calling base.Awake() in the derived methods should be done, since your base handles the inventory slots. It helps maintain clean code without repetition.

One change you may want to do is add an argument to Awake() that defines the slot count. If you want to make inventories of the same type but different sized, you can easily do so without having to create a completely new class for the different sizes.

PlayerInventory.cs: (or any other inventory)

```
public override void Awake (int numOfSlots) {
    this.numberOfSlots = numOfSlots;
    base.Awake ();
    Debug.Log ( "PlayerInventory.Awake" );
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated; overriding certainly makes more sense. I tried that to begin with, but didn't get it to work for some weird reason, but now it works just fine.

It's good to know that I'm not doing something extremely wrong :), and that was probably what I was after. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot add a parameter to `Awake`, the derived version will complain about no suitable method found to override.  And you can't add a parameter to `Awake` in the base behaviour because Unity won't allow it.

Comment: I didn't mention the `override` vs `new` issue because it's irrelevant - it's a Unity message callback, so the method will never be called by user-code regardless.  There's no way to misuse it.

Comment: To be clear: I don't want to alter the behavior of Awake(), thus I won't be sending anything to it. I do want, however, the derived objects to inherit everything from each other, while the base class contains most of the code. Imagine AstronautPlayer derives from Player, and the only (...) change is "gravityForce". I want to set that "gravityForce" in the Astronaut class, not when I'm creating it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is fine, though if you don't like it, just create a `CreateSlots(int numSlots)` method in the base-class and call it from the child.

Comment: I will keep in Awake() for now, because it doesn't make sense to create/awake an Inventory object without any slots, so to me it makes sense to have the slots creation at creation/awake time. If you disagree, please let me know! I appreciate all the wisdom you guys have! :)